# C++ my initialized string disappears when I leave the default constructor but my other member variables values don't

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to test a hangman program. The problem I'm running into is that in my default constructor I initialize my member variables. Wrong and Guess's values get saved so theres no issue there but my other member variables THE_WORD and soFar don't get saved. I think though my issue is with my header file. I think I messed up in my Hangman file with the declarations of my member variables for the THE_WORD and soFar. If someone can help in figuring out my issue(giving me the solution I would also love) I would be really grateful because this has been eating my brain for a really long time. Thanks!

In my main cpp file I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "player.h"
#include "hangman.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Hangman game1;

    while(1)
     {



       game1=Hangman();//error object of type hangman cannot be assigned
                       //because its copy assignment is implicitly delated


     }
```

In my player.h file I have:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>


using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    void MakeGuess(char &guess);
    void Win();
    void Lose();
    char Agree();
    void display();
private:
    string name;
    int score;
    string myString;
    char answer;

};

#endif
```

In my Hangman file I have:

```
#ifndef HANGMAN_H_
#define HANGMAN_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

class Hangman
{
public:
    Hangman();
    void Play();
protected:
    Player player2;
    vector<string> words;
    const string THE_WORD;//I think the issue is here
    string soFar;//I think the issue is here
    string used="";
    int wrong;
    char guess;
    const int maxwrong=4;
    //void virtual RespondIncorrectGuess();
};


#endif
```

In my implementation file I have:

```
    #include "hangman.h"
    #include "player.h"

    Hangman::Hangman()
    {
        wrong=0;
        guess='a';
        words.push_back("MONKEY");
        words.push_back("HANGMAN");
        words.push_back("DIFFICULT");

        const string THE_WORD = words[2];//this might be the key to solving my issue

        cout<<THE_WORD<<endl;

        string soFar(THE_WORD.size(),'-');
        cout<<soFar<<endl;

    }

void Hangman::Play()
{

    cout<<"This is the word now:"<<THE_WORD<<endl;//outputs nothing
    cout<<"Now the number of - is:"<<endl;
    cout<<soFar<<endl;//outputs nothing
    exit(1);
}
```

UPDATE:: In my short code I have in my test.h file

```
#ifndef test_test_h
#define test_test_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


class test{
public:
    test();
    void setName();
    string getName();
private:
    string name;
};
#endif
```

In my implementation cpp file I have:

```
#include "test.h"

test::test()
{
    name="hi";

}

void test::setName()
{
    cout<<"Input name"<<endl;
    cin>>name;

}

string test::getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

In my main file I have:

```
#include "test.h"

int main(){

    test student;

    student.setName();
    cout<<student.getName()<<endl;
    test::test();
    cout<<student.getName()<<endl;//this prints out the name i set earlier instead of the default name which I don't understand


}
```

Comment: You're declaring a new, short-lived variable called `THE_WORD` that shadows the member.

Comment: @Biffen I tried that before but then I get an error saying No viable overloaded '='

Comment: You'll need to put it in the initialisation list even, since it's const. Compiling with `-Wshadow` (or whatever the flag may be for your compiler) would have helped you catch this.

Comment: Please change `const string THE_WORD` to `string THE_WORD`.  Having `const` member variables  is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Later on towards the end of my code I called the default constructor: Hangman::Hangman(); (That way I can reset the game of hangman and therefore I can reset my member variables but as soon as I leave the scope they don't get saved? I don't understand why that's happening

Comment: @user5001170 can you show your code? it's not possible to "call the constructor" for an object that already exists

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have updated the question with my short code illustrating my issue along with a comment that shows the issue!

Comment: @user5001170 `test::test();` has nothing to do with `student`, can you explain why you think it would change `student` ? That's like saying `int x = 5;  int y = 2;` should change `x` to `2`

Comment: @MattMcNabb oh I see what you're saying! I assumed that when u called the default constructor it will relate to the class you made. How would I fix my error though because I know I cant just simply write student.test::test()? I dont know the synthax to recall that default constructor using the same class(test)

Comment: @user5001170 you cannot "recall the constructor" or anything. It's only used for creating an object.

Comment: If you want to make the object's variables be the same as a freshly constructed object , you could write `student = test();` (which creates a temporary fresh object and uses the assignment operator to copy the variables over)  ; or add a member function which clears the variables

Comment: @MattMcNabb do you mean like a destructor? If not how would I create such a member function? Also is there a way for me to make the object's variables be the same as a freshly constructed object from inside the function itself? I know i can't write student=test(); inside of my function

Comment: @user5001170 Inside what function?  You can write `student = test();` wherever `student` is visible. And if student is not visible then it doesn't make much sense to want to clear student.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ohh okay! One last question though I hope lol. So I changed the original main.cpp file  of my code : 

#include "player.h"
#include "hangman.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    Hangman game1;
    
    while(1)
    {
        
        game1=Hangman();//It says I cant include this
    }
}

Comment: that code is OK. Maybe you should start a new question including a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the exact error message

Comment: "because its copy assignment is implicitly delated" is because you have `const` member variables. Change those all to be non-const. As the other answers mentioned already, the const member variables are the root of all your problems. I don't know of any situation where a const member is a good idea.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ok but how do I make sure only one of my objects get destroyed because I don't want my score to get restart in player?

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `const string THE_WORD` in your Hangman ctor, you're not setting the member variable. Simple fix is just to put `THE_WORD` in the initializer list.

```
Hangman::Hangman() : THE_WORD(words[2]) /* other members should be init here */
{ ... }
```

edit; well, your ctor would need to be sent `words` for that to work.

Comment: Later on towards the end of my code I called the default constructor: Hangman::Hangman(); (That way I can reset the game of hangman and therefore I can reset my member variables but as soon as I leave the scope they don't get saved? I don't understand why that's happening?

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
    const string THE_WORD = words[2];

    string soFar(THE_WORD.size(),'-');
```

create local variables that are different from the class member variables.

**Solution**

`THE_WORD` has to be initialized in the constructor initialization list since its type is `const string`.

`soFar` can also be initialized in the initialization list. It can also be assigned a value in the body of the constructor.

Use

```
Hangman::Hangman() : THE_WORD("HANGMAN"), soFar(THE_WORD.size(),'-') {
...
}
```

or

```
Hangman::Hangman() : THE_WORD("HANGMAN") {
   ...

   soFar = string(THE_WORD.size(),'-');
}
```

You can obviate the need to store `THE_WORD` by providing a function that returns a reference to it.

```
const std::string& getTheWord() const { return words[2]; }
```

Comment: @R Sahu But what about THE_WORD? It appears I also created a local variable for that but how do I fix that? I tried including THE_WORD = words[2]; in the default constructor but i got an error saying no viable overloaded '='

Comment: @R Sahu I could do it that way but I wanna store my words in a vector using push_back  and then choose one of them to get stored into THE_WORD. Am I making things complicated? How can I make sure that the words I push_back into the vector gets saved?

Comment: @user5001170, in that case, it will be better to have a function that returns the `THE_WORD`. `const string getTheWord()  const { return words[2]; }`

Comment: @R sahu thank you I think omitting THE_WORD is probably the best idea. I dont even know y i included it in the first place its just making things more complicated lol. Gonna stick with words[x] where x is a random number from 0-2 that ill generate through rand() and srand (time(NULL));

Comment: @R Sahu i do have another question though. Later on towards the end of my code I called the default constructor: Hangman::Hangman(); (That way I can reset the game of hangman and therefore I can reset my member variables but as soon as I leave the scope they don't get saved? I don't understand why that's happening

Comment: @user5001170, it's not good to use comments to get answers to additional questions. You might want to create a new SO post to ask that question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the constructor.  You are declaring local variables with the same name as the member data.  Just remove the type portions, and the constructor will use the data members you intended.  Good to go.

In the `Hangman` declaration:

```
string THE_WORD;//I think the issue is here
private:
void setTheWord( string newWord );
```

and in the constructor:

```
setTheWord( words[2] );
```

Comment: @ donjuedo I don't know how to do that for THE_WORD. I tried using the line: THE_WORD = words[2]; but got an error saying no viable overloaded '='

Comment: @user5001170:  I see.  You've declared it a const, but assigned it a value from a variable.  You'll have to choose.  You could take away the const, and make a private setter.  That may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @ donjuedo Later on towards the end of my code I called the default constructor: Hangman::Hangman(); (That way I can reset the game of hangman and therefore I can reset my member variables but as soon as I leave the scope they don't get saved? I don't understand why that's happening

Comment: @user5001170:  Ah, there is a better way than calling the constructor again.  (when calling the constructor method like that, which object pointer is "this" -- it's not spelled out, so there is no place to save what you meant).  There are two good ways to reset the game.  One is to delete the old object and create a fresh new object.  And the other is to use an init() method, by any name you like, which resets all the values you want for a new game, but using the same original object.